# Select just Date/DateTime fields SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
show fields from table where type in ('date', 'datetime')
```

Returns the fields I want, is there a way to put this output in:

```
select * from table
```

i.e. replacing the *?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but this should work.

```
/* set your values */
SET @tablename = 'mytablename';
SET @schemaname = 'mydbname';
/* end */

SET @columns = '';
SET @query1 = '
(SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(`COLUMN_NAME`) INTO @columns 
FROM 
    `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE 
    `TABLE_SCHEMA` = ? 
AND 
    (`DATA_TYPE` = "datetime" OR `DATA_TYPE` = "date")
AND 
    `TABLE_NAME` = ?)';
PREPARE smtm FROM @query1;
EXECUTE smtm USING @schemaname, @tablename;


SET @query2 = CONCAT('SELECT ', @columns, ' FROM ', @tablename);
PREPARE smtm FROM @query2;
EXECUTE smtm;
```

Comment: Maybe this could be simple for people knowing SQL, but I liked this a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. At least not in an easy way, as you can't dynamically specify DB schema elements in a query in MySQL.  So you can't for example do:

```
SELECT (SHOW FIELDS ... ) FROM table
```

You could potentially create a stored procedure to dynamically build an SQL prepared statement (or do similar in an application/script with a programming language).

Comment: @juanpastas Of course you are getting an error.  I specifically said that you CAN'T do something like that. I was stating that as it seems your hope was that something like that was possible.  What I am saying is that it is not.  You have to literally build a string containing the SQL statement you want by some means (either in application logic, or in a stored procedure) and then execute it, as MySQL will not allow dynamic naming for database schema elements in a query like that.